# Jquery Dropdown Display Default Div

Tags: jquery

I have the following JQuery, I want to display the default divarea1 visible when the user goes to the page, I am newbie to Jquery so any help would be great.

Best
SPS

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.box').hide();
         $('#dropdown').change(function() {
             $('.box').hide();
             $('#div' + $(this).val()).show();
         });
     }); 
</script> 


 <select id="dropdown" class="boxformwh" name="dropdown"> 
    <option style="margin:20px;" value="area1"><b>DIV Area 1</b></option> 
    <option style="margin:20px;" value="area2"><b>DIV Area 2</b></option> 
    <option style="margin:20px;" value="area3"><b>DIV Area 3</b></option> 
 </select> 


  <div>
    <div id="divarea1" class="box">DIV Area 1</div> 
    <div id="divarea2" class="box">DIV Area 2</div> 
    <div id="divarea3" class="box">DIV Area 3</div> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.box').hide();
         $('#divarea1').show();
         $('#dropdown').change(function() {
             $('.box').hide();
             $('#div' + $(this).val()).show();
         });
     }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to trigger the `change` handler on page load as well, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').hide();
  $('#dropdown').change(function() {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('#div' + $(this).val()).show();
  }).change();
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/hz6RW/), calling [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) without any arguments is a shortcut to [`.trigger('change')`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) which will run the handler you just bound...so it'll use the initial value of the dropdown on page load.

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly hiding all `.box` elements, so you need to show `divarea1` element explicitly as well. The `onchange` will bork as expected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.box').hide();
         $('.box:first').show();
         $('#dropdown').change(function() {
             $('.box').hide();
             $('#div' + $(this).val()).show();
         });
     }); 
</script>
```

Changed to show the first `.box` div, that was not tied to a specific `div` and will show first.